# Images being requested multiple times from CSS

Tags: css, firebug, safari

Any idea what would make a stylesheet(s) load images multiple times?  The images are the same URL, nothing fancy going on.

---

EDIT: Only happens in safari (5.0.3) in both iPhone "mode" and default "mode" - i cannot reproduce the problem in FF or IE.

Apache_access_log says that the image is indeed being accessed multiple times.

When adding styles that call the image back in one-by-one, they don't seem to follow any pattern as to when they will start to double up.

I also tried making the image significantly smaller to see if it was a cache issue.  Didn't change anything.

Comment: I think CSS files are requested concurrently, so unless the image was loaded before the CSS files are requested, it might load the image multiple times.

Comment: do have some kind of cache busters in your urls (i.e. a random number as query string appended to the url?, like `/someimage.jpg?1234346758`)

Comment: nope -- the image is always the same URL, and .htaccess ignores images.  i do have multiple css sheets -- i'll have to grep 'em and see if the number of loads matches up with the number of sheets with that img in them.

Comment: The the image urls redirect (302)? As 302's are not cached.

Comment: nope -- when they are cached, i'm getting 304's.  I'm doing mobile development, so I'm just trying to keep first load down to as small as possible.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Happens only on iOS and Mac Safari. Images gets loaded 10000 times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the deal is with Safari, but apparently:

If the CSS rules that reference the same sprite-sheet are not grouped together, it will request the image more than once. (Although not the full number of times the call appears).

```
#divOne, #divTwo, #divThree {
    background-image: url('IMGURLHERE');
}
```

This would request the image one time.

```
#divOne {
    background-image: url('IMGURLHERE');
}

#divTwo {
    background-image: url('IMGURLHERE');
}
```

This would request the image twice.

*No idea as to why this happens.*